# Can app engine gradle plugin use java version 17?

Tags: java, gradle, google-app-engine, plugins, java-17

I'm running a gradle project locally with appengine.I could see that it still makes use of java 8 even though I have deleted java 8 from my machine. Is it possible to make it use my locally installed version 17? In case you are wondering, this is my build.gradle file

```
 buildscript {
  ...
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:2.5.0'
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:4.4.1.3373"
  }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine-appenginewebxml'
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
    targetCompatibility = '17'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['../']
    }
}

dependencies {
   ...
}

ext.getAppVersion = { ->
    return project.property('version')
}

appengine {
    tools {
        cloudSdkVersion = '449.0.0'
    }
    run {
        jvmFlags = ['-Dappengine.fullscan.seconds=5']
        projectId= 'beta-v2'
        services = '../war'
        port = 8080
        automaticRestart = true
    }
}

war {
    duplicatesStrategy = 'exclude'
}

explodeWar {
    with copySpec {
        from '../war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml'
        into 'WEB-INF'
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using App Engine Standard or Flexible? Have you checked if this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/setting-up-environment?tab=java) would be applicable to your application?

Comment: @RobertG I'm using app engine standard. Does that support running java 17 in local?

Comment: Yes it supports Java 17. Please check this documentation on [Java runtime environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/runtime).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 17 in your runtime environment based on this documentation on [Java runtime environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/runtime). Your `app.yaml` should have the `runtime` version indicated:

```
runtime: java17
```

You can also check this documentation on [using Gradle and the App Engine Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/using-gradle).

If the aforementioned steps didn't work, I would suggest filing an issue through this [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) or through this [Github issue link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/issues) so that Google Cloud engineers could take a look at this and provide you further assistance.

Comment: My project is a appengine-web.xml based project. I've updated it to java17 there. How do I verify if it is using java17 or not?

Comment: Please check this [Github link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/main/appengine-java17-bundled-services) wherein the only difference between a Java8 application and a Java17 application is in the `appengine-web.xml` file where you need to define the Java17 runtime and declare you need the App Engine APIs.

Comment: Yes. I just want to know if my local app engine server is using java17 as well. Because without <app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis> caused an issue after deployment but worked just fine in the local appengine server. What could be the reason?